# Cannot Access SharePoint Lists in Performance Point DashBoard Designer

Tags: performancepoint

I am in the midsts of planning for an upgrade from MOSS 2007 to SPS 2010, and we are looking for quick-wins for the client, one of which being PerformancePoint 2010 integration with SPS 2010. So i am tooling around, following some basic tutorials of creating scorecards/kpis/filters/dashboards all from the contoso sample data, which is all fine and well, but my client doesn't have a datawarehouse, and doesn't plan on moving to one.

This puts me in the situation where I need to be able to create these pieces from SP Lists instead of an analysis services DB/DW. I go through and create the data connection, and all seems to be working fine...In the data connection windows, I can click the View tab and preview the data, and actually see all the data thats in the task list I've created and linked to (all demo data, just created a couple of tasks and etc).

Now the trouble comes when I try to create a simple scorecard based off of this list. When I am in the Create tab, and click Scorecard, (Use Tabular > SP List) I can select my data source (Task Tracking Data Source) and thats all well and good.

I then go to the SharePoint Site tab (on the select data source on the wizard), I am able to select my Task Tracking Data source as well. When I get to the KPI screen, though, (if I wanted to build a KPI here) the only KPI name/actual I can use is "Attachments".  There is no way to add any other values to this, such as status, etc.  This is confusing to me, and I'm not sure why.

Furthermore, assume I do not make any KPIs, nor measure filters/member columns (which, incidentally, I can select valid/existing fields from the list), I get to the editor of my new score card, but I have no controls to drag over. On top of all of that, the bottom side of the detail pane (Data Source) has a drop down menu, and its set to "No Data Source" with nothing else to choose from. Conversely, when I use the contoso datawarehouse, I can see the name of the data source in that drop down.

So, I have been searching around for a tutorial, any advice, or just a point in the right direction. I was hoping you'd be able to help me.

The real question is, how do I get my SP List to show up in that data source drop down once I am in the 'create scorecard' mode of DashboardDesigner.  Like I said, I am able to select the data source when I am using the Analysis Services DB, and I am able to grab the fields.  If I were able to see the SP List in the data sources of the detail view of the scorecard, I'm assuming I'd be able to grab the controls.

Any advice?

Comment: Silly question but sometimes they evade us: do you have permission on the list you're trying to access?

Comment: Please refer to the tutorial at this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/performancepoint/creating-simple-budget-kpis-from-sharepoint-lists)

Answer (score 1):

I do have permission on the list.  It looks like it MAY be an issue that SP only allows you to create KPI off of numeric data fields, and since attachments is boolean that is the only option I have.  That still does not solve the problem of trying to get the data source(sp list) and its fields/cols to display when I'm designing a scorecard or report.  Sorry, I coulnd't log in to my old account, but I'm still the OP on this thread.

Comment: Also, I couldn't comment/reply to your original comment, so I apologize for posting this in the answers section.  I think it may have to do with the mix up of my original posting account.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your question about KPIs: "When I get to the KPI screen, though, (if I wanted to build a KPI here) the only KPI name/actual I can use is "Attachments". There is no way to add any other values to this, such as status, etc. This is confusing to me, and I'm not sure why."
If you load the data source and then click the View tab, you can set the column types. Columns set to Fact should become available as KPIs in a scorecard.
(I didn't repro your "No Data Source" issue. My SP List data source is selected in the dropdown)

6/6/11 Regarding no data source in the dropdown, did you create the Attachments KPI? If not, this might explain it: "You'll have to drag at least one KPI (from "KPIs" shown in your screenshot) out to the scorecard surface before the Data Source dropdown does anything. Scorecards are KPI-driven."

Answer (score 0):

When you set up a data connection for a SharePoint list, it will attempt to determine what fields are Time, Dimensions, and Measures based on the data type.  If you have fields in your list that you want to use as measures (typically numeric) it should have identified them as measures.  For example, if you just created a new custom list in Sharepoint (and didn't add any additional fields) you will have one measure (Attachments) and one dimension (Title).  However, you can control how it treats the fields in the list.

Open up the list data connection in dashboard designer, and go to the preview tab (the fourth tab).  You can select columns, and change their type in the panel on the right-hand side.  You can also hide columns (which I typically do the the attachments field since it is of no use).

Note that if you add additional fields to the list in SharePoint, you need to open the data connection up again in dashboard designer and resave it before they will show up on the scorecard design screen.

Sorry, I don't have any of this in front of me, so I'm describing it from memory.